# Extract Key Value from string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$myString = "Name=Tony;Fee=10;Account=Premium"
$splitString = "$($myString)".Split(";")

$name = $splitString -match "Name=(?<content>.*)"
$acct = $splitString -match "Account=(?<content>.*)"

$name 
$acct
```

Result:

```
Name=Tony
Account=Premium
```

How can I get it to return just the value?  Example:

```
Tony
Premium
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), with a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) and its `-Regex` switch:

```
$name, $acct = 
  switch -Regex ("Name=Tony;Fee=10;Account=Premium" -split ';') {
    '^(?:Name|Account)=(?<content>.*)' { $Matches['content'] }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using `-Split` and taking advantage of the text's format using `ConvertFrom-StringData`

```
$name, $acct = "Name=Tony;Fee=10;Account=Premium" -split ';' |
    ConvertFrom-StringData | ForEach-Object {$_.name,$_.Account}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) here to to construct a hashtable of key value pairs:

```bsh
$myString = "Name=Tony;Fee=10;Account=Premium"

# Create hashtable
$ht = @{}

# Spit string by ';' and loop over each item
foreach ($item in $myString -split ';') {

    # Split item by '=' to get key value pair
    $pair = $item -split '='

    # Set key value pair into hashtable
    $ht[$pair[0]] = $pair[1]
}

# Output values you want
$ht.Name
$ht.Account

# Tony
# Premium
```

Which also is beneficial if you need to lookup other values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response everyone.  They are work.  Really appreciated.